# How to convert image as a text from server to javascript image?

Tags: javascript, java, canvas, javax.imageio

I'm writing image as ImageIO output in servlet.

```
BufferedImage combined = null;


      int w = 1080;
      int h = 960;
      combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, 1);

      Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
      g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      for (int size = 0; size < imageList.size(); size++) {
        g.drawImage((Image)imageList.get(size), 0, 0, null);
      }
      g.dispose();
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
      response.setContentType("text/plain");

      ImageIO.write(combined, "png", out);
      combined.flush();
      response.setStatus(200);
      out.close();
```

How can I read that image from javascript and display in HTML page?

Comment: What is a javascript image?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm calling this service as a POST api call. I want to read this in javascript and display into HTML page.